# Spring autowiring service that implements interface

Tags: spring, service, interface, autowired

We got the following problem at hand. We need to autowire this service:

```
@Service       
public class myService implements ServiceInterface {}
```

We want to be able to access all methods of the autowired myService class not only the methods declared in the ServiceInterface. Problem is it seems we have to autowire this service by using the Qualifier/Resource Annotation, but with

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myService")
ServiceInterface noGoodService;
```

we can´t access all methods of myService. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to access methods not in the interface? This basically defeats the purpose of an interface. So basically you have an architectural issue here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the actual code you use, and you have nothing like transactions or any other AOP stuff declared in your configuration, you should be perfectly fine by injecting the actual service. However in general Spring will create proxies based on some configuration, like transactions, security etc.

By default spring will create a JDK Dynamic proxy, which is interface based. A class is dynamically created, which implements all interfaces of the service (Those nice myService$proxy1 classes). This class is not an instance of `myService` but of `ServiceInterface` and as such that dynamic object cannot be cast to that type.

Either define the methods you need on the interface (that is the whole purpose of the interface isn't it, else the interface is pretty useless) or use classbased proxies, which would require CGLib on the classpath.